# Why aren't these strings equal? (Python)

Tags: python

```
def getValue(d, key):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        print "{0} == {1}".format(k, key)
        if k == key:
            return v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            getValue(v, key)
    logging.error("Cannot find key in dictionary")
    return ""

#d = getting the dictionary

getValue(d, "error_frames")
```

From the print statement I inserted in the function, I clearly see "error_frames == error_frames" appear in the console, but the if statement is not getting executed. Why? The dictionary is constructed by parsing xml with the module xmltodict.

Comment: Try printing `repr(k)` and `repr(key)` instead of using `str.format`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the print statement is being executed from a nested recursive call.

```
    elif isinstance(v, dict):
        getValue(v, key)
```

Should that be `return getValue(key)`?

Comment: Good catch (+1) : my gut feeling is that this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 12):

`.format` calls the `__str__` method of the object and its output can be identical for different objects.

```
In [1]: a = 1

In [2]: b = '1'

In [3]: print '{0} == {1}'.format(a, b)
1 == 1

In [4]: a == b
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: I think that what you mean is that `.format` calls `__str__` -- In this case, print is calling `__str__` on a string object, which just returns a string.